# How to add pages to feed?

Tags: pages, feed

I'd like to include Pages in my RSS feed. Whenever I add or edit a page, I'd like it to show up in the feed. I can't seem to find any setting in the default WordPress installation or in the default (TwentyTen) theme.

How can I achieve this? I'm using the latest version of WordPress (3.1.3).

Comment: Try the [RSS Includes Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-includes-pages/) Plugin? (Note: completely untested. This Plugin was last updated a year ago, and last tested against WordPress 2.9.2.) EDIT: Here's another one that will create a Feed for Pages: [WCM Page Feeder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-feeder/) Plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following code to your theme's `functions.php` will solve your problem:

```
// Add Pages to RSS Feeds
function myfeed_request( $qv ) {
    if ( isset( $qv['feed'] ) && ! isset( $qv['post_type'] ) )
        $qv['post_type'] = array( 'post', 'page' );
    return $qv;
}
```

Found code [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-custom-post-types-to-your-main-wordpress-rss-feed/).